# Fixing "global" issue with program?

Tags: python, function, global

Originally I had "global" statements inside of the deposit and withdraw functions. I was told by my professor that I cannot use global statements for this assignment. There is a variable at the top that was created by Codio and I cannot move that.
I have to access that variable in my functions, which I did. Now I need to get my functions to return in such a way that the "account_balance" variable updates after each withdrawal and deposit. Currently the code functions mostly okay, but after each operation on the money, I type "b" for the balance function and the previous operations are wiped away and I'm back at the default balance. What am I doing wrong here? Code is below:

```
    import sys

#account balance 
account_balance = float(500.25)


#<--------functions go here-------------------->
#printbalance function
def balance():
  print('Your current balance:\n%.2f' % account_balance)


#deposit function
def deposit(temp):
  deposit_amount = float(input('How much would you like to deposit today?\n'))
  temp = temp + deposit_amount
  print('Deposit was $%.2f, current balance is  $%.2f' % (deposit_amount, temp))
  return temp

#withdraw function
def withdraw(temp2):

  withdrawal_amount = float(input('How much would you like to withdraw today?\n'))
  if withdrawal_amount > temp2:
    print('$%.2f is greater than your account balance of $%.2f ' % (withdrawal_amount, temp2))
  else:
    temp2 -= withdrawal_amount
    account_balance = temp2
    print('Withdrawal amount was $%.2f, current balance is $%.2f' % (withdrawal_amount, temp2))
    return temp2

#User Input goes here, use if/else conditional statement to call function based on user input

userchoice = ''

while userchoice!= 'Q':
  userchoice = input('What would you like to do?\n(B)alance?, (W)ithdraw?, (D)eposit?, (Q)uit?\n')
  userchoice = userchoice.upper()

  if (userchoice == 'B'):
    balance ()
  elif userchoice == 'W':
    withdraw (account_balance)
  elif userchoice == 'D':
    deposit (account_balance)
  elif userchoice == 'Q':
    print('Thank you for banking with us.')
    break
```

Comment: if you've learnt about classes this would be a good place to use them…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the value you pass to your functions is a copy, not a reference to the original.  You could do one of two things:

1. Use a global statement within the functions
2. Store the return value from the functions into the global variable

### First Option

I take it this is what your professor said is not allowed:

```
def deposit():
  global account_balance
  deposit_amount = float(input('How much would you like to deposit today?\n'))
  account_balance = account_balance + deposit_amount
  print('Deposit was $%.2f, current balance is  $%.2f' % (deposit_amount, temp))
  return account_balance
```

### Second Option

```
while userchoice!= 'Q':
  userchoice = input('What would you like to do?\n(B)alance?, (W)ithdraw?, (D)eposit?, (Q)uit?\n')
  userchoice = userchoice.upper()

  if (userchoice == 'B'):
    balance ()
  elif userchoice == 'W':
    account_balance = withdraw (account_balance)
  elif userchoice == 'D':
    account_balance = deposit (account_balance)
  elif userchoice == 'Q':
    print('Thank you for banking with us.')
    break
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are not allowed to use global variables, you need to use the variables returned by the deposit and withdraw functions.

```
while userchoice!= 'Q':
userchoice = input('What would you like to do?\n(B)alance?, (W)ithdraw?, (D)eposit?, (Q)uit?\n')
userchoice = userchoice.upper()

if (userchoice == 'B'):
  balance ()
elif userchoice == 'W':
    new_balance = withdraw(account_balance)
    if new_balance:
        account_balance = new_balance
elif userchoice == 'D':
    account_balance = deposit (account_balance)
elif userchoice == 'Q':
    print('Thank you for banking with us.')
    break
```

The withdraw function either returns the new account balance, or it prints that you don't have enough money in the account. After calling the withdraw function(), you check to see if it returned anything. If so, you update account_balance with the returned value stored in new_balance.

For the deposit function you just have to update account_balance with the value returned by the function.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation

Comment: Thank you. I did provide additional insight for one of his functions. The other answers don't take into account when the function returns None instead of a number.

Comment: @SorinSirghe thank you for the help. I got two different ways to make my program work now so I have some wiggle room to play with. Awesome explanation